# pydotplus does not import -- trying to visualize gradient boosting tree

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pydot

My goal is to visualize the results of a gradient boosting classifier.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier 
clf_gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('SELECT', selector), ('GBC', clf_gbc)])
parameters_gbc = {'GBC__min_samples_split': [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
             'GBC__max_depth': [3,4,5,6,7,8],
             'GBC__min_samples_leaf': [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=parameters_gbc, cv=cv, scoring = 'f1')
grid.fit(features_train, labels_train)
clf=grid.best_estimator_

import pydotplus
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
graph.write_pdf("gbc.pdf")
```

I get the error `ImportError: No module named pydotplus`. I installed pydotplus using `pip install pydotplus`.

Any help on this or on how to visualize the results of a gradient boosting classifier would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try : `conda install pydotplus` ? Are you using jupyter notebook (installed with Anaconda) ?

Comment: I tried `conda install pydotplus` in the cmd line and I get an error that says `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels`. Yes, I'm using jupyter notebook installed with Anaconda